# Youtube like timeline with sparks scrubbar

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I would like to transform my current scrubbar into a youtube like timeline.
Like when you hover the scrubbar on a certain point in time a thumbnail is shown.
Also that point should have a different colour on the scrubbar.

Is this possible or do I need to use another component and how?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I did but couldn't find any good results

Answer (score 0):

Google does some extra work when they add a video. They generate those thumbnails. And theirds them ahead of time. That is why you can see thumbnails of sections ov video that have not loaded yet. If you want to make one yourself, you need to generate thumnails of each video you would use. An ide would be to include the timecode into the file name. So for a flv called MyVideo, you would have thumbs for MyVideo001.jpg for one second, etc.

Comment: But what i would like to know is how to extend or customize the scrubbar so it shows a thumbnail when you hover it at a precise time moment, and give that moment another color on the scrubbar. Lets say for example the entire scrubbar is gray, then i want it to be yellow at 5 seconds and when you hover the yellow part a thumbnail is shown.

Comment: You have to write your own seekbar, you won't be able to get what you want extending the Seekbar class. Luckily, its not that hard to write your own and improve on Adobe's. Here is one I wrote that may get your headed in the right direction:
https://github.com/zfoley/Improved-FLV-Seekbar